Find my phone - Samsung vs Google
My Samsung S23 was stolen while on vacation in Rome.   I'm trying to use my Samsung android tablet to remote wipe the device.  I've learned that there are two alternatives to finding / wiping /locking the device.
Most obvious is Google's "Find my Device" feature. I've posted separately the issues I had with using it, but here I'm asking if anyone has experience with both tools. For the Samsung tool, I found the URL 'smartthingsfind.samsung.com'. After logging in with my Samsung account, it showed my tablet and my s23 phone, and offered to 'track location' and 'erase data', which I tried.
Has anyone had experience using the Samsung tool, as opposed to the Google tool? I generally find Google's tools to be somewhat effective, but since my phone is Samsung could there be an advantage in using a Samsung solution?

On the "why " we can only guess. May be because they copy everything Google has? Samsung Browser, Galaxy Store, Cloud backup and sync, Find my Mobile, Samsung Email, ...

Asking "why" is off-topic because it's opinion-based. Not only Samsung, but Xiaomi also has its own "Find My Device" service. Maybe because they don't want to depend on Google, or they see them as a rival instead? (Also, Google is blocked in China).

What I really want to know is, has anyone actually used the Samsung version with any success and could there be any issues in using both. There's always a chance that the Samsung version could be better at locating a Samsung device. I'm stuck in the middle of nowhere right now with nothing but a small tablet desperately trying to make sure my phone gets wiped.

Now that's a fair question, reopened :)
